# Why is this considered an aggregate?

Tags: r, casting, aggregate

I have used the `mtcars` data frame to attempt the following `cast`:

```
cast(melt(mtcars, id = c("cyl","carb")), cyl+carb~variable)
```

I understand that adding a function will produce an aggregation, but why, with the above code, do I get the following message:

> Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default

It would seem to me that the above code follows the basic structure of a `melt` and a non-aggregation `cast`, but apparently it is assumed by R to be an aggregation.

How would I produce a non-aggregation cast of that code that simply restructures the data by `cyl` and `carb`?

....Of course, it is possible that I'm simply misunderstanding the concept of aggregation and casting altogether. I've been working at it for the past few hours, and this is the best I've come up with.

Comment: Your grouping variables "*do not identify a single observation for each output cell*" as per `?cast`, therefore, you have to aggregate.

Comment: That makes sense--I retried the code with different grouping variables, namely `cast(melt(mtcars, id = c("mpg","wt")), mpg+wt~variable)`, and it produced a restructured data frame. Thanks for noticing that and pointing it out.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if you like to close it off. :-)